# What is the meaning of "decompose" in the following question?

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across the following question :

Decompose the transformation (z is complex) M(z) = (az+b)/(cz+d)
into :

1. z to z+d/c
2. z to 1/z
3. z to -(ad-bc)z/c^2

Also show z to 1/z is conformal.

What am I supposed to do in the "decompose" part of the question? Do I have to find relations/values of a,b,c& d such that M(z) would be same as the given transformations or something else? Just confused about the word.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure about the definition of $M(z)$? Besides, where is this taken from?

Comment: Sorry, typing error, it was cz+d not cz+b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be sure, since the question is ambiguous, but I suppose that the idea is to define$$f(z)=z+\frac dc,\quad g(z)=\frac1z,\quad\text{and}\quad h(z)=-\frac{(ad-bc)z}{c^2}$$and to compare $M$ with $h\circ g\circ f$. It turns out that$$M(z)=h\bigl(g\bigl(f(z)\bigr)\bigr)+\frac ac.$$

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally thought that 1,2,3 were supposed to be separate parts and not a combination.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @A.Random You weren't wrong in thinking of them as separate parts. Separate parts are often combined to form a whole, depending on the what kind of "combining" is going on. In this case "combining" means "composition of functions".